# Ant Javac target using different JRE from Eclipse? - "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to use an Ant script to build my Vaadin 6 project. When I manually build and deploy the project, it works (mostly), but when I use the ant script, I get compile-time errors.

My ant target looks like this:

```
<target name="build" depends="copyconfig" description="Compiles Java code to build directory">
    <javac destdir="build" includeantruntime="false"> <!-- Error here --> 
        <src path="src" />
        <src path="generated" />
        <src path="config" />
        <exclude name="**/*_Ex??.java" />
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

In eclipse: `windows-> preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs` I point to: `jdk1.7.0_03`. In `windows -> preferences -> Java -> Compiler` I set `compiler complience level: 1.7`

When I build via `Project->Build project` I get no errors, but when I build via the ant script, I get: 
 
`C:\vaadinSpikeWorkspace\DocumentManager\build.xml:55: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

I assume that my ant script is using a different version of the compiler and that's what's causing the problems (which don't appear when I compile manually via eclipse).

However, I was under the impressionm that JREs were backwards compatible: I.e. if I'm using the newest version of the JRE (1.7) I shouldn't have issues with different compiler versions?

Any help you provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Eclipse Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations -> Ant.build check the Jre version here.

Comment: Spot on! That's what I needed: Ant was configured to run 1.6 and wasn't using the central eclipse runtime configurations like I thought.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` means that you have compiled your code against JDK 7 but you're trying to run using JRE 6.

Inside your Eclipse you are using the JDK 7, but in your Path you probably have an older Java version.

```
java -version
```

may help you.